# Get function arguments from outside without executing this function in javascript

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, arguments

Is it possible to receive the arguments list of the function without executing it somehow? I can't find a normal solution unfortunately.

I'm working on some Dependency Injection system and I'd like to know arguments naming in the function (service) before I create the instance of it. Because I want to create the Dependencies first and then pass them into the function (service).

for ex:

```
function MyServiceA(myServiceB) {
  say() {
     ...code.........
     myServiceB.beep();
   }
}

function MyServiceB() {
  beep() {
     ...code.........
   }
}

function Creator() {
  // Is it possible to receive it somehow? this is the question
  const argumentsList = MyServiceA
  // iterate list and instantiate the ServiceB dependency and inject in into the MyServiceA

  argumentsList.forEach(dependency => {
   const dependencyInstance = new dependency()
   new MyServiceA(dependencyInstance )
 })
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You could turn the function into a string, and then parse that string to find the names of the arguments. AngularJs did something like this for its dependency injection. Be aware that if the code gets minified, the names will change and this can break your code.

```js
function needsA(a) {
  console.log("in needsA");
  a();
}

function needsB(b) {
  console.log("in needsB");
  b();
}

function needsAandB(a, b) {
  console.log("in needsAandB");
  a();
  b();
}

const dependencyLookup = {
  a: () => console.log('in A'),
  b: () => console.log('in B'),
}


function injector(fxn) {
  const argNames = fxn.toString()
    .match(/^function\s*[^\(]*\(([^\)]*)\)/)[1]
    .split(',');
  const dependencies = argNames
    .map(str => dependencyLookup[str.trim()]);
  
  fxn.apply(null, dependencies);
}

injector(needsA);
injector(needsB);
injector(needsAandB);
```

A useful article on angularjs's dependency injection: https://teropa.info/blog/2014/06/04/angularjs-dependency-injection-from-the-inside-out.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use `func.name` to get a function's name and `func.toString()` to get its source code and extract arguments with regular expressions. But with ES6 we have plenty variants like rest arguments, destructuring and so on. So you need a real parser like AST to get detailed information about a function's arguments.

```js
const funcs = [ data => foo(arg1, data), () => true, (arg1, arg2 = null)=>true, function (arg1, arg2) {}, function restParams({arg1, arg2}, [arg3, ...rest], ...arg4) { return false; }];

for(const func of funcs){
  
  let args = [];
  let name = func.name || 'anonymous';
  if(func.length){
    args = func.toString()
      .match(/(?<=function\s+[^(]*\()[^=)]+/);

    if(!args){
      args = func.toString()
        .match(/(?<=\(*\s*)[^()]+?(?=\s*\)*\s*=>)/);
      name = 'arrow';
    }
  }
  console.log('function name:', name);
  console.log('arguments:', ...args);

}
```